# SSAS Cube calculation Scope with criteria

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I need your help with a scope definition where the Goal is to create (in this case) a site  = "TAI API", that is the aggregation of two other sites

---

```
"CPH API" + "US API" where product 
    in ([Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[BANT],[Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[BZNT],[Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[VANT]))
```

What I have done is creating the site as follow:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Order Company Group].[Parent].[All].[TAI API] 
as [Order Company Group].[Parent].&[10440 - API]+[Order Company Group].[Parent].&[10240 - API]
, VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Then I would like to define a scope for this site "TAI API", so that it works for any measure, but I am unsure what the next step is... I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work as intended:

```
SCOPE ([Order Company Group].[Parent].[All].[TAI API] ) ;<br/>
this = ([Measures].??<br/>
,([Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[BANT],[Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[BZNT],[Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[VANT]));<br/><br/>
END SCOPE;
```

The `[Measures].??` is to indicate that I am not sure if this is needed or what to write...

Turns out I can do something like this

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Order Company Group].[Parent].[All].[TAI API] 
as [Order Company Group].[Parent].&[10440 - API]+[Order Company Group].[Parent].&[10240 - API]
, VISIBLE = 1  ;<br/><br/>

SCOPE ([Order Company Group].[Parent].[All].[TAI API]);<br/>
SCOPE([Product].[Manufacturing Family].[Manufacturing Family].members
- [Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[BANT]  
- [Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[BZNT]
- [Product].[Manufacturing Family].&[VANT]   
);<br/>
this = null;
<br/>
END SCOPE;
<br/><br/>

END SCOPE;
```

Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope w/o any measures references:

At the very beginning (I just used my own DB with sample on standard Year-Month-Day dimension):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Create Date].[Create Date].[Month].&[201402].[20140200]
 AS null, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Data'  ;
```

And than scope at the end:

```
SCOPE ([Create Date].[Create Date].[Month].&[201402].[20140200]);
THIS = SUM({[Create Date].[Create Date].[Day].&[20140214],[Create Date].[Create Date].[Day].&[20140228]});
END SCOPE;
```

This will work even with calculated measures with Descendants (e.g. ...Exists(Descendants([Create Date].[Create Date].[Year].&[2014],[Create Date].[Create Date].[Month],SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)...)

Please see this image. Is it expected result?

[image: CalcMemberOfSomeDim]

If so, you can just set first time NULL to this new member. And that in scope write

```
SUM([Order Company Group].[Parent].&[10440 - API],[Order Company Group].[Parent].&[10240 - API])
```

Hope it helps.